# partial derivatives of a function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)$ is not equal to $(0,0)$ and $f(0,0) = 0$

I am trying to check the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ at $(a,b)$ not equal to $(0,0)$

Now $f_x$ = $lim_h \rightarrow 0$$\frac{f(a+h,b) - f(a,b)}{h}$

which on complutation yields

$f_x$ = $lim_h \rightarrow 0$$\frac{ba^2+b^3-abh-2a^2b}{a^2+b^2}$ which is equal to $\frac{ba^2+b^3-2a^2b}{a^2+b^2}$.

But the answer sheet says that $f_x$ does not exist at such points.

Help, please

Comment: That function has partial derivatives at every point.

Answer (score 1):

As the composition of continous and differentiable functions this function has partial derivatives with respect to both $x$ and $y$ at every point but the point $(0,0)$. For this point we can check the definition:
$$f_x(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h, 0)- f(0,0)}{h} =0$$
$$f_y(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}=0$$

Therefore the function has partial derivatives at every point.
Note however, that it is not a $C^1$-function because the function itself is not even continuous at $(0,0)$.